Will submissions to special issues of journals be sent to referees only after their deadline?
I have submitted a manuscript to a special issue of a math journal one month ago. The deadline for submission papers to that special issue is 30 of January 2025. Do I have to wait to the end of January, or will the manuscript be evaluated to be sent to reviewers/desk rejected before the deadline? I ask because the status of my manuscript has not changed since I submitted.

I don't think there's any universal rule. It could be either, depending on how the editors choose to organize it.

I'm not the editor, but if I were, I'd act as follows. I think many others would act similarly, but there is no universal.
I need to assume that as editor of a special issue, I'm something of an expert in the stated topic of the issue, not just a publisher's functionary.
You might get desk rejected almost immediately on submission. I'd want to review submissions more or less as they occur and if they are off topic or "cranky", you would get rejected "now". This clears my desk.
I'll also assume that the special issue has a more or less firm publication date, some months beyond the deadline date. Given that, I would not want to wait until the deadline to begin sending out review requests. This gives reviewers more time and makes completion prior to review deadlines more likely. I wouldn't want to get backed up to the production deadline. Also, some reviewers might look at more than one paper if they finish a review quickly.
As reviews come in, I would keep a more or less sorted list of the submissions in likelihood of publication acceptance. But I wouldn't send out any acceptances or rejections until the submission deadline. I would, however, be fairly likely to send out revision requests as it becomes obvious that they are warranted, even prior to the submission deadline. I want the best possible issue and it is also courteous to give "hopeful" papers maximum time to improve.
Note the two assumptions. First, I know the topic, and second, I have a production deadline. Without those it could be quite different.
And note that the online notice (accept/reject/...) won't be updated until decisions are made and maybe not at all until the submission deadline.
Finally, note that a possible further assumption is that the editor works periodically on the issue rather than wait until they absolutely must act. In that case, you won't learn much of anything until late. I dislike that system both for my personal work habits and for fairness to everyone involved, giving them options.
Under my system, you probably haven't been desk rejected and probably won't be unless the paper is fairly marginal and submissions are slow.
